# Is there any way to customize the numpy.rint funtion?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding

I have a numpy array

```
a = np.array([[[0.23,0.81],[0.9,0],[1,0.51]], [[0.3,0.75],[0.1,0.2],[1,0.50]]])
```

To round it as integer, there is a function numpy.rint.

```
a_round = np.rint(a)
```

It round up when the value is greater than 0.5 and round down when the value is less than 0.5. So my output was:

> [[[0. 1.]   [1. 0.]   [1. 1.]]
>
> [[0. 1.]   [0. 0.]   [1. 0.]]]

Issue is, is there any way to customize the logic of round up? For example if I want to get a round up when the value is greater than .3 and a round down when the value is less than 0.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to do that:

```
>> a = np.array([[[0.23,0.81],[0.9,0],[1,0.51]], [[0.3,0.75],[0.1,0.2],[1,0.50]]])
array([[[0.23, 0.81],
        [0.9 , 0.  ],
        [1.  , 0.51]],

       [[0.3 , 0.75],
        [0.1 , 0.2 ],
        [1.  , 0.5 ]]])

>> np.rint(a)
array([[[0., 1.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[0., 1.],
        [0., 0.],
        [1., 0.]]])

>> np.where(a<0.3, np.floor(a), np.ceil(a))
array([[[0., 1.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1.],
        [0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is another simple way to do it for numbers in range [0,1] by converting boolean to float:

```
>> (a>=0.3).astype(np.float)

array([[[0., 1.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1.],
        [0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]]])
```